# Goroutines deadlock recursive

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

I have a DFS recursive function which gives me all possible routes in a directed graph.
And I can't precisely know when it finishes.

```
func dfs(data map[int][]int, path []int) {
    datum := path[len(path)-1]
    value := data[datum]
    for i := 0; i < len(value); i++ {
        if !contains(path, value[i]) {
            new_path := append(path, []int{value[i]}...)
            if len(new_path) > len(max_path) {
                max_path = new_path
            }
            dfs(data, new_path)
        }
    }
}
```

I try to execute this function on goroutines for different cases. In order to reduce time I use goroutines. (By the way it really speeds things up like 10x or much)

```
for _, node := range nodes {
        if is_touching_wall(node) {
            wg.Add(1)
            go dfs(graph, []int{node})
        }
    }

    wg.Wait()
```

As you can understand here, I call wg.add(1) but i don't call wg.Done() later. So it creates "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!".

I tried to find the time when DFS finishes, in order to call Done() but couldn't manage it.

Is there any other way to cancel goroutines if they are going to be deadlocked or should i try another approach here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that you will gain much, if any, using goroutines the way you do for this approach. If the DFS is running on a tree, then you can potentially split it into disjoint sections and use goroutines on each. With a directed graph, you have no idea if nodes traversed by one goroutine are also being traversed by others.

Nevertheless, in order to deal with the deadlock, you must call `wg.Done` when a goroutine ends. A simple way of doing it is:

```
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
   defer wg.Done()
   dfs(graph, []int{node})
}()
```

This will not solve your real problem though, only the deadlocks.

Comment: Actually for my algorithm it doesn't matter if nodes traversed by one goroutine are also being traversed by others. Because i create goroutine for every start point of my DFS. For example DFS can start node 1-2-3-4. I create 4 goroutines for them. Each one of them finds possible paths from their starting point. Then everything settles I make comparisons.

Comment: But as you said because I have to call Done() , this approach won't work :)

Comment: Call `Done` as I showed, it should work. Note that you create a goroutine for each node. This is unlikely to run faster than a sequential algorithm.

Comment: Oh, it worked like a charm thank you ! By the way without goroutines, for huge data set ,execute time took 45.2459234s. With goroutines for each start point, it took 6.9810789s.
It's more than enough improvement for me :)